# How to install python3 and Django using userdata in AWS EC2 with aws cli boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to install python3 and django via user data on EC2 instances. I know I can do it with Cloudformation or directly on EC2 but I need to install and deploy it via user data. I am creating the VPC and autoscaler but I need to automate the install and deployment of python3 and django automatically.

Here is what I have but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    UserData="""#!/bin/bash
            yum install httpd php php-mysql -y
            echo y | sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip
            sudo pip install --upgrade pip
            python3 -m venv venv
            source ./venv/bin/activate
            pip install django
            pip install --upgrade pip
            yum update -y
            service httpd start
            chkconfig httpd on
            adduser Eteram
```

I have tried enclosing them in the double quotes but still doesn't work.

I am basically trying to install python3 and django and deploy a test application to be able to go to the django admin url.

If I run the above commands on the EC2, it runs just fine. But when I include it in the user data, after I login to EC2 and check the cloud init log, I see the following:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 3: echo y | sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-p
ip: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 4: sudo pip install --upgrade pip: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 5: python3 -m venv venv: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 6: source ./venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 7: pip install django: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 8: pip install --upgrade pip: command not found
```

Comment: This will be running as root, so sudo should probably be unnecessary. The AMI might not even have sudo? Also, you should use `yum install -y` instead of echoing y.

Comment: Good points, trying it now.. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I had to do get things working.

Here are the instructions to install python 3 and django  on aws using boto3 within user-data

```
    UserData="""#!/bin/bash
            yum install httpd php php-mysql -y
            yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip -y
            pip install --upgrade pip
            cd /home/ec2-user
            python3 -m venv /home/ec2-user/venv
            source /home/ec2-user/venv/bin/activate
            pip install django
            pip install --upgrade pip
            yum update -y
            service httpd start
            chkconfig httpd on
            """
```

thanks to the tip from @dpwrussell I had to remove sudo since it's not required. next, I had to change directory to get the virtual env under my user home.

Comment: Thank you for writing this down..!